# Not able to return posts by user id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

When trying to fetch all the posts by a user id, cosmos DB only return an empty array, but when using mongo DB through atlas, it returns all the posts by that user. What am i doing wrong.

```
exports.postsByUser = (req, res) => {
    Post.find({ postedBy: req.profile._id })
        .populate("postedBy", "_id name")
        .select("_id title body created likes")
        .sort("_created")
        .exec((err, posts) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: err
                });
            }
            res.json(posts);
        });
`enter code here`};
```

I receive a http status of 200, but with just an empty array. and when i try fetching all the posts by all users it returns.

Comment: I'm not sure but I've been struck by the sort by _created while in the select field appears created. Is it possible that this is an error and, as the sort field does not exist, it returns an empty array?

Comment: Here is a silly idea, comment populate, select and sort, and see if it will return anything, if it does, u know what to debug, if it doesn't check if profile_id is correct, and try converting it to mongoose.Types.ObjectId before filtering

Comment: My god... i did comment out, something i have done before, but i never did the .sort(_created).. it was it!!! Thank you :)

Comment: @noitse You can add your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be "the answer" but it is a suggestion which will bring others to the correct answer in their case.

For those who run into bugs like these, the easiest way to find out what is happening and which step is making the unexpected return is to comment out all the pipeline steps, in this case, populate, select and sort. Then debug from there - if it returns anything, if there is no result you can start from your match case (find), if it does return you can move to next pipeline step and so on.

Taking some time debugging yourself will make you understand your code better, and you will find the answer yourself faster than waiting for someone on stackoverflow to give u suggestions.